# Materializecss sidenav not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design, materialize

I am trying to get the sidenav to work for the Materializecss framework.

MATERIALIZECSS http://next.materializecss.com/getting-started.html

SIDENAV DEMO http://next.materializecss.com/sidenav.html

MY CODEPEN https://codepen.io/gregoryksanders/pen/RxoyqB

```
<head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.2/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="slide-out" class="sidenav">
        <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>First Link With Icon</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">Second Link</a></li>
        <li><div class="divider"></div></li>
        <li><a class="subheader">Subheader</a></li>
        <li><a class="waves-effect" href="#!">Third Link With Waves</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" data-target="slide-out" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

3 Days trying to figure this out :/ so any help is welcomed.

Comment: "It's not working" is not helpful. Post what you expect to see and what you actually see.

Comment: On your codepen sidenav seems to be working, what is the issue you are having?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you should initialize the side-nav in Javascript code like this

```
 var elem = document.querySelector('.sidenav');
  var instance = new M.Sidenav(elem);

   // with jquery

  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.sidenav').sidenav();
  });
```

now your code will work perfect

```js
 var elem = document.querySelector('.sidenav');
  var instance = new M.Sidenav(elem);

  // Initialize collapsible (uncomment the lines below if you use the dropdown variation)
  // var collapsibleElem = document.querySelector('.collapsible');
  // var collapsibleInstance = new M.Collapsible(collapsibleElem, options);

  // Or with jQuery

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sidenav').sidenav();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.2/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="slide-out" class="sidenav">
    <li><div class="user-view">
      <div class="background">
        <img src="images/office.jpg">
      </div>
      <a href="#!user"><img class="circle" src="images/yuna.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#!name"><span class="white-text name">John Doe</span></a>
      <a href="#!email"><span class="white-text email">jdandturk@gmail.com</span></a>
    </div></li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>First Link With Icon</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Second Link</a></li>
    <li><div class="divider"></div></li>
    <li><a class="subheader">Subheader</a></li>
    <li><a class="waves-effect" href="#!">Third Link With Waves</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" data-target="slide-out" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    

</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

On the [materialize website](https://materializecss.com/navbar.html), this code is given to initialize Sidenav bar

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
    var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems, options);
});
```

but You modify This code and remove option in var instance and now code look like and you should paste this code in  your script tag  or your javascript file

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
    var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems);
});
```

Now I explain what is the problem in upper code that given on the [materialize website](https://materializecss.com/navbar.html)
in code, variable instances give 2 arguments 1st argument is elems and 2nd argument is the option that is not defined in your code so you remove the option argument in this code to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Initialization is the most important thing when using materialize.js, for example i want to initialize a carousel.

```
  // Javascript

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
    var instances = M.Carousel.init(elems, options);
  });

  // Or with jQuery

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel();
  });
```